# Update column with max date before entered date

Tags: sql, postgresql

TABLE A:

```
id - primary key
order_date - timestamp
last_updated - timestamp
company_id - company table's primary key
```

TABLE B:

```
id - primary key
company_id - company table's primary key
last_updated - timestamp
creation_date - timestamp
```

I'm trying to update TABLE A's last_updated column to a value from TABLE B's last_updated column. Both tables have duplicated entires in all columns other than PK columns.

Here is my thought process, but I can't get the SQL right:

1. For each row in TABLE A, I need to find a matching company_id on TABLE B
2. Let's say 25 results were found from TABLE B for that company_id. Out of these 25 results, I need to find the row in TABLE B that has the MAX creation_date that's before TABLE A's order_date.
3. This will take the result down one. And this row's last_update value will be copied to TABLE A's last_updated column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be quite expensive, but you can approach this with a correlated subquery:

```
update a
    set last_updated = (select b.last_update
                        from b
                        where a.company = b.company and
                              b.creation_date < a.order_date
                        order by creation_date desc
                        limit 1
                       );
```

For performance, you want an index on `b(company, creation_date, last_update)`.